# Is this argument by the author really ok? ($(\mathcal{G},\tilde{d})$ is complete.) (in "Set Theory and General Topology" by Yohei Komori)

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces

I am reading "Set Theory and General Topology" by Yohei Komori.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.
Let $\mathcal{F}:=\{\{x_n\}\mid \{x_n\}\text{ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$}\}$.

> Lemma 3.59:
> Let $\{x_n\},\{y_n\}\in\mathcal{F}$.
> Then, $\{d(x_n,y_n)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.
> So, $\{d(x_n,y_n)\}$ is a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

> Definition:
> $\{x_n\}\sim\{y_n\}:\Leftrightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,y_n)=0.$

> Lemma 3.61:
> The above binary relation $\sim$ is an equivalent relation on $\mathcal{F}$.

> Definition:
> $\mathcal{G}:=\mathcal{F}/\sim$.

> Definition:
> Let $[\{x_n\}],[\{y_n\}]\in\mathcal{G}$. ($[\{x_n\}]$ is an equivalent class to which $\{x_n\}$ belongs.)
> $\tilde{d}([\{x_n\}],[\{y_n\}]):=\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,y_n).$
> Then, $\tilde{d}$ is well-defined.

> Lemma 3.62:
> $(\mathcal{G},\tilde{d})$ is a metric space.

> Definition:
> $i$ is a mapping from $X$ to $\mathcal{G}$ such that $i(x)=[\{x\}]$.

> Lemma 3.63:
> $i:X\to\mathcal{G}$ is isometry and $\mathcal{G}=\overline{i(X)}$.

> Lemma 3.64:
> $(\mathcal{G},\tilde{d})$ is complete.

> Proof of Lemma 3.64 by the author:
> Let $\{x^{(m)}\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(\mathcal{G},\tilde{d})$.
> For any positive real number $\epsilon$, there exists a natural number $n_0$ such that $m_1,m_2>n_0\implies\tilde{d}(x^{(m_1)},x^{(m_2)})<\epsilon.$
> Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$.
> Let $\{x_n^{(m)}\}\in x^{(m)}.$
> Since $\{x_n^{(m)}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$, there exists $n^{(m)}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n_1,n_2>n^{(m)}\implies d(x_{n_1}^{(m)},x_{n_2}^{(m)})<\epsilon.$
> Since $\tilde{d}(x^{(m_1)},x^{(m_2)})=\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n^{(m_1)},x_n^{(m_2)})$, $d(x_n^{(m_1)},x_n^{(m_2)})<\tilde{d}(x^{(m_1)},x^{(m_2)})+\epsilon<2\epsilon$ for $m_1,m_2>n_0$ and for sufficiently large $n$.
> So, for sufficiently large $n$ such that $n>\max\{n^{(m_1)},n^{(m_2)}\}$, $d(x_{n^{(m_1)}+1}^{(m_1)},x_{n^{(m_2)}+1}^{(m_2)})\leq d(x_{n^{(m_1)}+1}^{(m_1)},x_{n}^{(m_1)})+d(x_n^{(m_1)},x_n^{(m_2)})+d(x_{n}^{(m_2)},x_{n^{(m_2)}+1}^{(m_2)})<\epsilon+2\epsilon+\epsilon=4\epsilon.$
> So, $\{x_{n^{(m)}+1}^{(m)}\}$ is a Cauchy sequenece in $(X,d)$.
> Let $x:=[\{x^{(m)}_{n^{(m)}+1}\}]\in\mathcal{G}.$
> We prove that $\{x^{(m)}\}$ converges to $x$.
> For sufficiently large $m$, $d(x_m^{(l)},x_{n^{(m)}+1}^{(m)})\leq d(x_m^{(l)},x_{n^{(l)}+1}^{(l)})+d(x_{n^{(l)}+1}^{(l)},x_{n^{(m)}+1}^{(m)})<\epsilon+4\epsilon=5\epsilon.$
> So, $\tilde{d}(\{x_m^{(l)}\},\{x_{n^{(m)}+1}^{(m)}\})<5\epsilon+\epsilon=6\epsilon.$
> So, $\{x^{(m)}\}$ converges to $x$.

I cannot understand what the author is saying.

I think $n^{(m)}$ depends on not only $m$ but also $\epsilon$.

Is the above argument by the author really ok?

If this is a fatal error, I don't want to read this book anymore.

Comment: For a given $\epsilon$ the value $n^{(m)}$ does depend on $\epsilon$ . This is not an error.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you very much for your comment.